# continuously check the status (connected/disconnected) of mobile network (2g/3g/4g) using PhoneStateListener in android when app is not running

Tags: android, networking, phone-state-listener

I want to update the details saved in the local db to server when my device gets connected to a network. Even my app is not running, I want to update the details. It All works fine when application is in foreground. But when app is closed, BroadcastReceiver with **android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)** not invoked when I turned on the mobile network (2g/3g/4g). I don't know how to continuously check the status (connected/disconnected/connecting/not connected) of mobile network (2g/3g/4g) using `PhoneStateListener`. Please help me to implement this feature.

Comment: Make your broadcast receiver static.

Comment: Please share your implementation of BroadcastReceiver. Did you register it in your manifest?

Comment: Yes. I had registered the receiver in Manifest and also in MainActivity for devices with os greater than 23.

This is my BroadCastReceiver code

public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            Log.e("NetworkChangeReceiver","Network change occurs, onReceive intent same");
            Log.e("NetworkChangeReceiver","Action received is: "+intent.getAction());
        }
    }
}